# Limit of a function defined as the sum of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Given a decreasing sequence $a_n$ of positive real numbers, for $x>0$ define 
$$
f(x)=\sum_n \min\left(\frac{x}{a_n}, \frac{a_n}{x}\right).
$$
Can $a_n$ be chosen so that $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to 0$?

Comment: Can we have floor function or terms have to be negative

Comment: I am sorry, $x$ is positive. (edited)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is negative. If $a=\lim a_n=0$, then at $x=a_n$ the $n$-th summand equals 1. If $a>0$, then for $x<a$ the sum diverges to infinity.